# What is the Masterpage equivalent in Java (Struts2)

Tags: java, struts2

I am quite new to Java EE, in the past I developed mostly on .NET. Soon I'll start with a project based on Java EE (using Struts2). I am sure that there is some way to create a Template for the site which can be changed quickly (something like the Masterpages in ASP.NET).

What solutions are there? Which is preferred?

Thanks in advance
Johannes

Comment: I've always found JSP .tag files to work great for templating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know ASP.NET and Masterpages but you might want to look into the [Tiles plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/tiles-plugin.html).

Edit: looking at the Masterpages documentation it seems like Tiles really is the equivalent you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a template for the site to use with Struts2, one option is to use [Sitemesh](http://www.sitemesh.org/overview.html)